# Android SQLite delete function

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am doing a delete function. The user will enter the ID number for them to delete some data. I can manage to get the input that user enter but cannot do the delete function. Where should I put this code in the code below?

```
Integer deletedRows = myDb.deleteData(result.getText().toString());

        if (deletedRows > 0)
            Toast.makeText(MenuAdmin.this, "Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(MenuAdmin.this, "Data not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the class. I want to put the code above into this class. I can't find where to put the code.

```
package com.example.user.unitenidol;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class MenuAdmin extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelp myDb;
    Button bViewIdol;
    Button bDeleteIdol;
    final Context context = this;
    private EditText result;
    String del;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_admin);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelp(this);

        bViewIdol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewIdol);
        bDeleteIdol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDeleteIdol);
        viewAll();
        DeleteData();

        result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);



        final Button bRegisterIdol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegisterIdol);


        bRegisterIdol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(MenuAdmin.this, RegisterIdol.class);
                MenuAdmin.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void viewAll() {
        bViewIdol.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                            // show message
                            showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Id :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Username :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Email :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                        }

                        // Show all data
                        showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void showMessage(String title, String Message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void DeleteData() {

        bDeleteIdol.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.promps, null);

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                context);

                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);


                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                // get user input and set it to del
                                                // edit text
                                                result.setText(userInput.getText());


                                            }

                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });



                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        alertDialog.show();

                    }

                });

    }    
}
```

Comment: post your sqlite database helper

Comment: Please don't `**bold**` things arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to delete a row in sqlite data base

```
 public boolean Delete(int rowId)
    {
        boolean Delete = false;
        try {
             Delete = mSQLiteDatabase.delete("your Table Name", "your column name" + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return Delete;
    }
```

usage:

```
if(Delete(2)){
   //your row was deleted
}
```